# How to add title at custom position in Latex pgfplot?

Tags: pgfplots, csv, tikz-node

I tried to add title at custom position of a pgfplot from a CSV (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xnF8rG9J50ZIxl9K04k6nksvjWoWrfHe/view?usp=sharing) file, but nothing came out. I tried several ways, actually... Any assistance is appreciated. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={\,}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}%[ xlabel=Pixels, ylabel=pixels]


\addplot[color=blue, only marks, mark size=0.3pt] table[y=yval, x=xval, col sep=tab]{data_g.csv};

 \end{axis} 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It produced :
 [image]

I want like as follows:
[image]

Comment: I have tried to add   \node at (250,255) {Correlation Coefficient $=0.923367$}, but it does not appear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several options, you can use a `legend` or simply a `node`, here's an example

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      samples = 500,
      domain = 0 : 200,
      xmin = 0, xmax = 250,
      ymin = 0, ymax = 250,
    ]

    \addplot[color = blue, only marks, mark size = 0.3pt] ({x + 10 * (1 - 2 * rand)}, {x + 10 * (1 - 2 * rand)});

    \node at (axis cs:250,250) [anchor = north east] {Correlation coefficient: 0.923367};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]